# Decision Tree visualization error in rattle Error: the FUN argument to prp is not a function

Tags: r, visualization, decision-tree, rattle

I created a decision tree in rattle for the in-built wine dataset.
The output is shown below

Summary of the Decision Tree model for Classification (built using 'rpart'):

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)

n= 124 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
      * denotes terminal node

 1) root 124 73 2 (0.30645161 0.41129032 0.28225806)  
   2) Proline>=953.5 33  0 1 (1.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000) *
   3) Proline< 953.5 91 40 2 (0.05494505 0.56043956 0.38461538)  
     6) Intensity< 3.825 44  0 2 (0.00000000 1.00000000 0.00000000) *
     7) Intensity>=3.825 47 12 3 (0.10638298 0.14893617 0.74468085)  
      14) Flavanoids>=1.385 13  6 2 (0.38461538 0.53846154 0.07692308) *
      15) Flavanoids< 1.385 34  0 3 (0.00000000 0.00000000 1.00000000) *

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = Class ~ ., data = crs$dataset[crs$train, c(crs$input, 
    crs$target)], method = "class", parms = list(split = "information"), 
    control = rpart.control(usesurrogate = 0, maxsurrogate = 0))

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] Flavanoids Intensity  Proline   

Root node error: 73/124 = 0.58871

n= 124 

        CP nsplit rel error  xerror     xstd
1 0.452055      0  1.000000 1.00000 0.075061
2 0.383562      1  0.547945 0.52055 0.070325
3 0.082192      2  0.164384 0.26027 0.054946
4 0.010000      3  0.082192 0.21918 0.051137

Time taken: 0.02 secs
```

The rules are listed below

```
Tree as rules: 

 Rule number: 2 [Class=1 cover=33 (27%) prob=1.00]
   Proline>=953.5

 Rule number: 14 [Class=2 cover=13 (10%) prob=0.38]
   Proline< 953.5
   Intensity>=3.825
   Flavanoids>=1.385

 Rule number: 15 [Class=3 cover=34 (27%) prob=0.00]
   Proline< 953.5
   Intensity>=3.825
   Flavanoids< 1.385

 Rule number: 6 [Class=2 cover=44 (35%) prob=0.00]
   Proline< 953.5
   Intensity< 3.825

[1] 2 6 1 5 3 7 4
```

The output plot which I got is shown below 
[image: The output of the tree plot]

When I try to plot the tree, it is showing only the outline of the nodes. Nothing else is listed. 
I tried with different datasets. All are showing the same result.  
All plots other than decision tree are working perfectly fine.

How to resolve this? Is this related to any package problem?

Comment: I do not understand your rpart code as it seems to not show the wine data as input but a different dataset. Could you also show the code you used in rattle to show the decision tree, I guess you used fancyRpartPlot?

Comment: You said that you used actually "Flavanoids Intensity  Proline" in your tree construction. In the wine dataset there is not a variable called Intensity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved It..
Removed the following packages and reinstalled

```
   remove.packages('rpart.plot')
   remove.packages('rpart')
   remove.packages('rattle')
   remove.packages('RColorBrewer')
```

Install them again from console (then it will install all the dependencies)

```
install.packages('rattle')
install.packages('rpart')
install.packages('rpart.plot')
install.packages('RColorBrewer')
```

Now reload the packages and it resolved the problem

```
library(rattle)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RColorBrewer)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rpart)
library(rattle)
```

I do not have sufficient information to answer your question and so I am not sure what is going wrong in your case. But please find below an example code to produce a tree using fancyRpartPlot.

```
model<-rpart(Type~ Flavanoids+Proline+Hue, data=wine)
fancyRpartPlot(model)
```

[image]

Comment: fancyRpartPlot(model) produces an error code Error: the FUN argument to prp is not a function.

Comment: Only boxes (blank white boxes as shown in the figure in the question )are plotted in the plots tab of RStudio. Same error is shown in case of rattle also

Comment: Which version of rattle do you have? Mine is Version 3.4.1.

Comment: All other plots are working fine..Problem is there only for decision tree

Comment: Could it be that your tree was created by a package that is not rpart?

Comment: When I try ctree and plot(ctree) its working. The error is shown for fancyRpartPlot

Comment: When you use fancyRpartPlot you should make your model with rpart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79101/discussion-between-dvs-and-ruthger-righart).